# How can I crush Spartacus default scss

Tags: css, carousel, customization, scss-mixins, spartacus-storefront

I use Spartacus carousel.
I want to make changes in the default scss for the carousel structure,but I can't customize the default scss.
How can I customize the default scss in Spartacus?

**Default scss:**

```
%cx-carousel {
  display: flex;
  flex: 100%;
  --cx-speed: 0.5;
  flex-direction: column;

  > h3 {
    @include type('3');
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
  }

  .carousel-panel {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    // The size of carousel items depends on the number of items per slide.
    // We generate 10 sizes in case there are a lot of carousel items displayed
    // on a single slide.
    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
      &.size-#{$i} .item {
        flex: 0 0 calc((100 / #{$i}) * 1%);
      }
    }

    .slides {
      flex: auto;
      position: relative;

      .slide {
        transition: 0.6s all;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;

        &:not(.active) {
          // we keep the active slide non-absolute, so the height
          // of the parent is based on the displayed slide
          position: absolute;
          opacity: 0;
          z-index: -1;
          transition: none;
        }

        .item {
          opacity: 0;
          z-index: -1;
          &.active {
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 1;
          }
          transition: 0.4s all;

          // we add a transition delay so that items are nicely animated in a sequence
          @for $i from 1 through 4 {
            &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
              transition-delay: calc(var(--cx-speed, 1) * #{$i * 0.25s});
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  button {
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
    color: var(--cx-color-light);
    &:not(:disabled) {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

  .indicators {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    button {
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0;
      transition: 0.6s all;
      background-color: transparent;
      &[disabled] {
        color: var(--cx-color-primary);
      }
      &:not(:disabled):hover {
        color: var(--cx-color-secondary);
      }
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-only(xs) {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .previous,
  .next {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 2rem;

    &:disabled {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    &:not(:disabled):hover {
      color: var(--cx-color-primary);
    }
  }
}
```

**I am trying to customize it this way:**

```
cx-carousel 
{
  @extend %cx-carousel !optional;
  .carousel-panel {
    .slides {
      
      .slide {
        display: webkit-inline-box;;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source :

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi! In the documentation it shows the folder where the styles are located and it states they are customizable. You can't modify them because of a project constrain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a few options to override the styles, mainly:

1. Skip the standard component styles, so that you introduce complete custom styles
2. Override component style rules with custom rules

#### Skip standard component styles

For the first option, you would add the following in your `styles.scss` file:

```
$skipComponentStyles: (cx-carousel);
```

You can also add `cx-product-carousel` to the list of skipped component styles. By adding those components styles, the final styles will exclude styles from the final css file for the given component.

**Please note** that the scss variable must be inserted *before* you import the storefront styles.

#### Override component style rules

For the 2nd option, you would keep the existing styles, and further amend the rules. You should use the component selector to ensure encapsulation of styles cross the app. Here's an example:

```
cx-carousel {
  border: solid 1px rebeccapurple;
}
```

**Please note** that the custom scss should be inserted *after* you import the storefront styles.

Comment: Worth to remember to delete imported Spartacus styles in angular.json and add them into src/styles.scss as it won't work to skip any style by $skipComponentStyles